# Why does document.elementFromPoint return null for elements outside visible document

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why does `document.elementFromPoint(500,1000)` [here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/) return null if that pixel is located outside the visible document when the document loads?

I've noticed `document.elementFromPoint` returns null for any point that is initially outside the visible document, as well as after it is scrolled into view.

A simple way to test this is in Chrome (*ctrl-shift-i -> scripts -> 'watch expressions'*) (ensure that the page height is narrowed to less than 1000 pixels)

**EDIT:** so it does make sense, as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

1. always returns null for points outside visible area
2. x and y are relative to the top left and right of visible screen

I failed on both assumptions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense that it returns no element when you specify a point outside the window. It returns elements that are visible at that point, not elements that would be visible there if the window had a different size. Consider that changing the size of the window may cause elements to move, so you wouldn't get a consistent answer if it did return elements that might be displayed at that point.

Regardless how you scroll the content in the window, a point outside the window is still outside the window.

Comment: so why does it return null when you scroll to that point, rendering it visible?

Comment: According to Mozilla docs it should return null when outside visible bounds, I I still don't get why it still returns null when it scrolls into view. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint

Answer (score 46):

So you kinda answered your own question: document.elementFromPoint works in the viewport coordinate rather than document. So all you need to do is to add a scroll compensation.

The following code worked out for me:

```
document.elementFromPoint(X - window.pageXOffset, Y - window.pageYOffset);
```

Or if you are listening for an event that would be:

```
document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX - window.pageXOffset, e.pageY - window.pageYOffset);
```

Comment: I found this on Google!  This what exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks so much :D

Comment: Thank Anton! You saved the day :)

Comment: this works! I was getting null because the element wouldn't have been visible if the client hadn't scrolled down from the top of the page - thankyou.

Comment: I can't make it work unless I actually scroll (element.scrollIntoView) the element into the viewport. If the elements outside of the viewport, scroll compensation doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have a working demo maybe?

Comment: @BenBracha — I think this answer answers a different question, namely: *"How do I make elementFromPoint() work when I have document coordinates, rather than viewport coordinates?"* and apparently that question-answer solves most people's problems.

Comment: @BenBracha — however the answer to the actual question in this topic, is that the element needs to be visible inside the viewport. And that's the other answer, by Guffa, above. — You can scroll the elem into view, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21779484/694469