# Javascript get element at point outside viewport

Tags: javascript

Is there something similar to document.elementFromPoint(x,y) that works for elements that are outside the viewport?

According to the MDN docs for document.elementFromPoint() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

> If the specified point is outside the visible bounds of the document
>   or either coordinate is negative, the result is null.

So obviously it doesn't work if you're trying to grab elements beyond the user's viewport.

Thanks!

Comment: This feature request is filed as https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20328 (no activity for 5 years though..)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hey I had the same issue, where if the element is not within the current bounds of the viewport `elementFromPoint` will return `null`.

I find that you have to scroll to the element location to make it visible in the viewport and then perform the `elementFromPoint`.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var api;
  api = function(x,y) {
    var elm, scrollX, scrollY, newX, newY;
    /* stash current Window Scroll */
    scrollX = window.pageXOffset;
    scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
    /* scroll to element */
    window.scrollTo(x,y);
    /* calculate new relative element coordinates */
    newX = x - window.pageXOffset;
    newY = y - window.pageYOffset;
    /* grab the element */
    elm = this.elementFromPoint(newX,newY);
    /* revert to the previous scroll location */
    window.scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY);
    /* returned the grabbed element at the absolute coordinates */
    return elm;
  };
  this.document.elementFromAbsolutePoint = api;
}).call(this);
```

You can simply use this command whenever the coordinates are absolute from the `pageX`,`pageY`.

```
document.elementFromAbsolutePoint(2084, 1536);
```

This code is also on GitHub packaged into a bower component for ease of including into projects.

https://github.com/kylewelsby/element-from-absolute-point

Hope this helps your project.