# document.elementFromPoint(x,y) for elements scrolled out of view

Tags: javascript, dom

[Document.elementFromPoint  (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) only works for currently visible elements, e.i. for elements currently visible on screen and not scrolled out of view.

Is there a fast way to retrieve an element at coordinates (x,y) even for elements that are not currently visible? I'd be doing it 1000 times for different points and would like to keep it under 100ms.

Comment: Simple answer: No. Hidden elements are exactly that: **Hidden**.  From what I remember they don't really have any coords since they don't show.

Comment: @Intervalia I'd use coordinates relative to the full document size, not the viewport.

Comment: The thing is that an element that is not showing does not have a `.clientHeight` or a `.clientWidth` and does not return a rect when you call `el.getClientRects()`. They are, for all intents and purposes, empty in size and living at `0,0`. If you are using `opacity:0` then they exist and should still get a hit. But with `display:none;` they are not available.

Comment: @Intervalia I meant hidden as in scrolled-out-of-view, not hidden as in `display:none`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get element at point outside viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715620/javascript-get-element-at-point-outside-viewport)

Comment: @Nickolay Thank you, that solution won't work for me though. I'd be getting 100+ elements and don't want to bother the user doing so. Seems I'll have to do it the hard way.